# Obtaining class name from using NSStringFromClass

Tags: ios, ios8

I am trying to obtain the class name of my custom class using NSStringFromClass method . Instead of the class name however I get the parent class (i.e `NSManagedObject`) . 
Below is the function call that is been used
`NSStringFromClass([[CoreDataManager sharedManager].xxx class]);` -->
This function returns `NSManagedObject` as the string rather than the class name xxx
The class XXX was defined as 
`@interface XXX : NSManagedObject`

Comment: How was the instance that xxx points to instantiated?

Comment: Did you also set your custom class XXX in the managed object model for your entity?

Comment: Sven , thank you for the pointer, yes I missed setting the custom class in my object model . You have seriously saved me hours of work !!